# sequelize-auto: Camel case in Programmatic API options

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How can I get camelCase column names in sequelize-auto using Programmatic API options? I've already tried like this:

```
const options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  directory: './models',
  port: '3306',
  logging: false,
  additional: {
      camel: true,
      timestamps: false
  }
}
```

and

```
const options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  directory: './models',
  port: '3306',
  logging: false,
  camel: true,
  additional: {
      timestamps: false
  }
}
```

But none of this seems to work, what am I doing wrong?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto/blob/master/lib/index.js it looks like you are close!  You just need to rename the `camel` option to `camelCase` as so...

```
const options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  directory: './models',
  port: '3306',
  logging: false,
  camelCase: true, // <-- Do this!
  additional: {
      timestamps: false
  }
}
```

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a camelCaseForFileName option. It is -f or --camelCaseForFileName on the command line, and programatically I used this:

```
var SequelizeAuto = require('sequelize-auto-v3')
var auto = new SequelizeAuto('money', 'root', '',{
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    output: './models',
    camelCase: true,
    camelCaseForFileName: true,
    // account_access_rules vs accountAccessRules:
    additional: {
        timestamps: false,
        underscored: false
    }
});

auto.run(function (err) {
...}
```

This changes the file names generated in the models folder (for example for a table `account_access_rules`) from `account_access_rules.js` to `accountAccessRules.js`

Sorry for making this an answer (as the question only asks about column names and this answer duplicates an answer about column names, and adds info about file names) but I could not show my working code in a comment.